# Rodar script escrito em Python em windows(Sem python instalado)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um script escrito em Python(3.6) que funciona normalmente se executado no meu PC(Que tem o Python instalado)

**Minha dúvida é:** Se eu rodar ele em algum outro windows que não tenha o python instalado, ele irá rodar normalmente? E se não funcionar, existe alguma maneira de faze-lo rodar sem que tenha que instalar o python no outro windows?

Comment: Infelizmente não. Como o Python não é uma linguagem nativa do Windows, o mesmo não consegue identificar a sintaxe do script para poder interpretá-lo. Você já procurou por alguma versão embarcada?

Comment: Hmm entendi, uma pena então, pensei que tinha alguma forma. Mas obrigado.

Comment: Você pode chamar o interpretador Python direto como uma função em C. Isso implica você escrever seu próprio programa que chame o interpretador, mas já é próximo o suficiente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voce pode "empacotar" o python junto com seu script, pela sua pergunta, me parece que o mais apropriado seria um "python compiler", duas opções interesantes são:

### [Nuitka:](http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html)

**TL;DR**
Nuitica é um compilador python, compatível com Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, and 3.5
Voce o alimenta com sua aplicação python e ele faz a "mágica", convertendo a app em um executável.

### [PyInstaller:](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

PyInstaller é um program que "empacota" aplicações python em um executável padrão, nos ambientes Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris e AIX. Sua principal vantagem em relação aos concorrentes: suporta as versões do Python de 2.7 a 3.5, e, graças à técnica transparente de compressão, cria executables pequenos.

Comment: Esta aparecendo um erro quando executo o Nuitka: "Error, cannot find "gendef.exe" which is required though."

Comment: Veja se [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33135837/2879341), te ajuda.

Comment: Ainda não consegui resolver, será que pode ser pq meu script foi feito em Python 3.6 ?

Comment: Consegui fazer rodar o Pyinstaller, ele empacotou em uma pasta e transformou em um exe. o Problema é que se tiro o exe dentro dessa pasta ele não roda. Tem algum comando pra que eu faça empacotar esses outros arquivos dentro do exe tambem?

Comment: Consegui aqui, só tive que acressentar --onefile no final. Valew pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução seria você distribuir junto com o executável, alguns arquivos necessários para a execução do Script no Windows. Você pode obter estes arquivos baixando o pacote embarcado disponível na página de downloads do Python: [clicando aqui](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). No arquivo que será baixado, vem vários outros arquivos, mas para sua necessidade poderá deixar apenas os três arquivos que seriam: **python.exe**, **python36.dll**, **python36.zip**

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Complementando... o arquivo a ser baixado seria o do título: "Windows x86 embeddable zip file"

Comment: Vou tentar fazer isso

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma é usar o **auto-py-to-exe** [clicando aqui](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/), podes escolher se queres executar em linha de comandos ou como uma "interface" do windows.

Certifica-te que tens o python até a versão 3.7 (a 3.8 exige outra forma de instalar diferente).